# ¿Como pasar datos de una cadena a otra view en Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, routes

Buenas comunidad estoy trabajando en un proyecto en laravel donde realizo un ecommerce. Estoy en la parte previa a la pasarela de pago, quiero que una vez el cliente termino de llenar el carrito sea redirigido a una vista donde se despliegue la orden en proceso que emitio, por eso una vez que este clickea en el link "proceder con el pago" el controlador crea una orden de su compra, lo que me esta fallando es poder enviar esos parametros de la orden a la vista siguiente, ya que lo unico que obtengo es un objeto tipo bool. Dejo mi codigo...

```
CartController.php
public function checkout()
{
    $cartotal = \Cart::getTotal();
    $order = new Order();
    $order->total = $cartotal;
    $order->status= 1;
    Auth::user()->orders()->save($order);
    $ide=$order->id;
    return Order:: findOrFail($ide);
}
```

Esto devuelve correctamente los datos de la orden que se emitio una vez el cliente procede a elegir el metodo de pago

```
{"id":70,"created_at":"2021-10-26T12:03:13.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-10-26T12:03:13.000000Z","user_id":1,"total":679,"status":1}
```

pero yo quiero mostrarlo en una vista, por eso necesito retornar, una vez entra al controlador, a una view.blade.php... Realice algo asi:

```
return view('finish', [
        'order' => Order:: findOrFail($ide)]);
```

Pero esto lo unico que me devuelve es un objeto tipo boolean, lo que yo quiero es poder ingresar a los datos de la orden en esta view, para poder iterar con estos datos

Answer (score 1):

Comunidad fue un error tan solo en la vista al no llamar correctamente a order, ya que lo estaba queriendo traer dentro de un for each, lo unico que hice fue cambiar eso y pude solucionar el problema. Estaba accediendo de esta manera

```
@foreach
{{ $order->status }}
@endforeach
```

Y la manera correcta seria:

```
{{ $order->status }}
```